# Disabling double click inside the IFRAME with remote source

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Folks,

We have one strange requirement where we want to disable double click inside the IFRAME.

The complication here is HTML response is coming from remote URL and we donot have any control over it. Is it possible to disable double click inside this IFRAME.

e.g.

Iframe src="http://removeserver/view.jsp" height="300px" width="300px">

Note : We already investigated and it seems because of cross side scripting we cannot do this.Basically we cannot access HTML elements of page remoteserver/view.jsp as it is coming from remote web site.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: is it ok to draw transparent div above and disable all clicks this way?

Comment: Yes it would be great. If you can give me sample code it will be helpful. I want to disable "double click" not single click.

Comment: it would disable single clicks, mouse clicks, scrolls, everything related to mouse...

Comment: Ok that should also do. Can you please share some code to start of with. Like how can we make DIV transparent on top of this IFRAME.

Answer (score 2):

Empty div above iframe will disable any mouse actions on iframe content
http://jsfiddle.net/uxUF8/63/

```
<iframe with="300" height="300" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/OsOYg5gpS0s" ></iframe>
<div style="position:absolute;margin-top:-300px;width:300px;height:300px;border:1px solid red;" ></div>
```

another version allows you to scroll inside http://jsfiddle.net/uxUF8/62/

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response. Today I tried putting this solution in place but we have 2 combo box also which user should be able to expand inside IFRAME.  So basic question is ALLOW CLICK and DISABLE DOUBLE CLICK inside IFRAME (Loaded remotely and have no control).

Comment: ...why double click is so bad?... just saw  - it is requirement - ignore.

Comment: Hi We are integrating our web page with external web site. On their page when you double click on specific IMAGE its size is doubling (ZOOMING) We just want to disable it. We are ok with other things.Any possibility of achieving this.

Comment: As you said, lots of things are forbidden in iframe, other solutions: ignore - usual visitor do not use double click on images, or use curl (with cache) to get content, parse it and show in a way you want